# Hyperlefger fabric validation on enrollmentId, affiliation and attributes

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

For the `register` and `affiliation add` APIs of the `fabric-ca-client`, what are the validations performed on these inputs.

1. **enrollmentId:**
   What is the max length supported?
   Are there any characters which will be invalid in an `enrollmentId`?
2. **affiliation:**
   What is the max length supported?
   Are there any characters which will be invalid in an `affiliation`?
3. **attributes:**
   What are the max `attributes` an identity can have?
   What is the max length of an `attribute`?
   Are there any characters which will be invalid in an `attribute`?

I have tested with `fabric-ca-client` locally, and it accepts `enrollmentId`, `affiliations` of more than **100 characters**. If the `CA` does not put any restrictions, I wanted to know if the HLF network has any limitations with regards to the `enrollmentId`, `affiliations` or `attributes`? For instance, if I create a certificate with Fabric CA which has a **10000 character enrollmentId**, will it work in the HLF network?